# Check DataType returned from 'Schema.FieldSetMember' getType() method in Apex class

Tags: apex, fieldsets

I have piece of code below:

```
for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : SObjectType.Vacancy_D2D__c.FieldSets.Tooltip_fields.getFields()){
   if(fsm.getType() == 'String'){
       tool += Utility.addTableRow(fsm.getLabel(), String.valueOf(d.get(fsm.getFieldPath())));
   }}
```

I just want to check what kind of data it has returned abd based on that I'll proceed. But I'm getting error as below.

> Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.DisplayType,
>   String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsm.getType()` return `Schema.DisplayType` value so to compare it with string data type you need to convert it into string.

```
for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : SObjectType.Vacancy_D2D__c.FieldSets.Tooltip_fields.getFields()){
   if(String.valueOf(fsm.getType()) == 'String'){
       tool += Utility.addTableRow(fsm.getLabel(), String.valueOf(d.get(fsm.getFieldPath())));
   }}
```

or you can also use `Schema.DisplayType.String`

```
if(fsm.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String){
           tool += Utility.addTableRow(fsm.getLabel(), String.valueOf(d.get(fsm.getFieldPath())));
       }}
```